# Rake issue when deploying ruby on rails

Tags: openshift

I have really been enjoying OpenShift until i tried to deploy a ruby on rails application. The application deploys correctly but when i send a http request to the website i get the standard ror webpage error message and this error message which appears in "rhc tail".

> [ 2015-09-12 03:15:10.4835 139977/7f5e103ca700 Pool2/Spawner.h:738 ]: [App 148847 stdout] 
>   [ 2015-09-12 03:15:10.7690 139977/7f5e103ca700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:849 ]: Could not spawn process for group /var/lib/openshift/55f3cf757628e18647000018/app-root/runtime/repo#default: An error occured while starting the web application.
>        in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::handleSpawnErrorResponse(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::NegotiationDetails&)' (Spawner.h:1172)
>        in 'Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::negotiateSpawn(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::NegotiationDetails&)' (Spawner.h:1135)
>        in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::DirectSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (DirectSpawner.h:213)
>        in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:782)
>   [ 2015-09-12 03:15:10.7692 139977/7f5e10e0c700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1971 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session. An error occured while starting the web application.
>   Error page:
>   You have already activated rack 1.5.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.6.4. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
>     /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup'
>     /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in`setup'
>     /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
>     /opt/rh/ror40/root/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in`'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in`rescue in require'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:212:in`run_load_path_setup_code'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:69:in `load_app'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:96:in`'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:4:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
>     /opt/rh/ruby200/root/usr/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:3:in`'
>   101.100.138.151 - - [12/Sep/2015:03:15:10 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 682 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"
>   101.100.138.151 - - [12/Sep/2015:03:15:11 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://cv-francismb.rhcloud.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36"

If you need any information to help me solve this problem i would be more then happy to supply it! All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error . case was also the same that I deployed my ruby on rails project on openshift . Deployment screen ended up with **success** message and no errors at that screen . but when i tried to check my web on production it gave me the error

> Website not currently working

Then i tried some google solutions and in the end I got my link working by going to my web host through ssh and then i entered in root-app folder and ran the following command

```
gem install rack
```

I made `Ctlr + F5` and got my app working -
 [Here](http://www.gerardcondon.com/blog/2015/06/15/upgrading-to-rails-4-dot-2-on-openshift/) is link for original source

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. I ran the following:

```
rhc ssh <myapp>       #where '<myapp>' was the name of my rails project
gem install rack
```

After a browser refresh, my app started normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack', '1.5.2'
```

Or else I would get problems with the version of rack not being the same one that the one deployed in OpenShift.